# Dynamic Tabs in bootstrap on .aspx pages?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a piece of code. I wrote a javascript in order to move to next tab when you click on tabs. However i want to move to next tab also when i click on a given button. my code fulfills my requirement, except, the moment i press next button on my one dynamic tab, page starts refreshing, although i have moved to next dynamic tab but as page refreshes i am thrown back to my initial tab. help please.(i am running this script on an aspx page, works fine on a html page)
(attached picture shows my dynamic tabs. i want to move to section b with a click on button on section a)

my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#myTab a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
});
 $(".btn-style").click(function () {
var target = $(".nav-tabs li.active");
var sibbling;
if ($(this).text() === "Next") {
    sibbling = target.next();
} else {
    sibbling = target.prev();
}
if (sibbling.is("li")) {
    sibbling.children("a").tab("show");
}
});
});
```

and a button like:

```
<button class="btn-style" type="submit">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a submit button which will by default post your form. Change

```
<button class="btn-style" type="submit">Next</button>
```

to

```
<button class="btn-style" type="button">Next</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it is^^